# Adding a layer over a PDF file using Kinetic JS

Tags: javascript, pdf, html5-canvas, layer, kineticjs

I'd like to add a layer over a pdf file (PDF JS) using Kinetic JS. The main purpose is to add annotation comments on a PDF file.

My problem, is that the canvas of the pdf file has different dimensions for each document.

Therefore how can I get the container of the Kinetic JS to match the dimension of the PDF Canvas?

If I turn it out more generally, how do I get a KineticJS container to fit a HTML5 Canvas with variable dimensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the container can be dynamically resized at any time:

```
  stage.setWidth(... get PDF width ...);
  stage.setHeight(... get PDF height ...);
```